# How can I stop Dynamic Web Module version from changing?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created new Spring Starter Project using STS:

- Maven Project
- Java 1.7
- Packaging: War

In order to run on Tomcat 7, I changed in Project properties "Dynamic Web Module" from `3.1` to `2.5`. (it was a tricky one, first you need to uncheck, apply and then it allows you to change the version)

I've cleaned the project and run on Tomcat. It was great. Then I wanted to add some dependencies in pom and when I clicked "Maven Update" the version was changed to `3.1`.

I didn't change any dependency in pom. Maybe there is here one that causes this trouble.

What should I do to stop this version from being replaced?

Edit:

Content of web.xml from /WebContent/WEB-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Here are my m2e installed versions:
[image]

Comment: Maven isn't changing anything, this isn't a Maven issue, but an Eclipse integration issue. Eclipse + m2e != Maven

Comment: Can you make sure you have m2e-wtp installed? Can you post your `web.xml` if you have one?

Comment: Your `web.xml` is not at the right place. Should be `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` as per [the standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), unless you somehow configured your POM otherwise, which I strongly suggest _not_ to do.

Comment: `web.xml` file was created by default in that location when I changed the version from `3.1` to `2.5`. Anyway, when I moved it to the location you mentioned the problem no longer occurred, so I guess you should post your answer, so I can accept it :)